# Records with overlapping dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an addresses table, say:

```
address_id  person_id  start_date  stop_date  address 
         1        123  01-JAN-15   01-JUN-15  india 
         2        123  01-MAY-15   null       russia 
         3        321  01-JAN-15   01-JUN-15  us
         4        321  10-MAY-15   null       india
```

I want to find all records (`address_id` values) which have overlapping dates for the same `person_id`. In this example that would find `address_id` 2 and 4, as May lies between Jan and Jun.

I then want to update the `stop_date` to `start_date - 1` of the subsequent row belonging to same person so that the overlap is removed. For instance updating `stop_date` to 09-MAY-2015`at row with`address_id` 3.

So I want to end up with:

```
address_id  person_id  start_date  stop_date  address
         1        123 01-JAN-15  30-APR-15    india
         2        123 01-MAY-15  null         russia
         3        321 01-JAN-15  09-MAY-15    us
         4        321 10-MAY-15  null         india
```

I have tried:

```
update (
select * from addresses a1,addresses a2
where a1.person_id = a2.person_id
and a2.start_date > a1.start_date and a2.start_date <a1.stop_date
)
set a1.stop_date = a2.start_date - 1;
```

This worked fine in Microsoft Access but in Oracle it an invalid identifier error for `a2.start_date`.

How can I perform this update?

Comment: Can you include your desire table after update?   Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I think you might have to handle null values as a special case in Oracle. You should check if a date `is NULL` before attempting to compare it.

Comment: address id   person_id  start_date          stop_date         address 
1                 123            01-JAN-15         30-APR-15        india 
2                 123            01-MAY-15         null                   russia 
3                 321            01-JAN-15         09-MAY-15        us
4                 321            10-MAY-15         null                   india      --desired table

Comment: its a self join of addresses table in subquery fetching results based on what I want to update the same addresses table

Comment: Please add new info to the question, particularly if it needs to be formatted to be readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated update:

```
update addresses a
set stop_date = (
  select min(start_date) - 1
  from addresses
  where person_id = a.person_id
  and start_date > a.start_date
  and start_date <= a.stop_date
)
where exists (
  select null
  from addresses
  where person_id = a.person_id
  and start_date > a.start_date
  and start_date <= a.stop_date
);

2 rows updated.

select * from addresses;

ADDRESS_ID  PERSON_ID START_DATE STOP_DATE ADDRESS  
---------- ---------- ---------- --------- ----------
         1        123 01-JAN-15  30-APR-15 india     
         2        123 01-MAY-15            russia    
         3        321 01-JAN-15  09-MAY-15 us        
         4        321 10-MAY-15            india
```

Both the `set` subquery and the `exists` subquery look for a row for the same person whose start date is between the start and stop date of the current row (which is the correlated part). The `exists` means only accounts which match are updated; without that any rows which don't have an overlap would be updated to null. (You wouldn't see any difference with the sample data, but would if you had more data).